# Как закрыть от публичного просмотра файлы внутри директории на сервере Nginx?

Tags: nginx

Есть папка с изображениями

```
/images/35/
```

35 - это номер фотоальбома.

Внутри нее лежат оригинальные фото и миниатюры:

```
/images/35/thumbs/
/images/35/medium/
/images/35/image.jpg
```

Можно ли в конфиге nginx как то прописать **deny all** для оригинальных изображений, но так, чтобы изображения из папок **thumbs/** и **medium/** были доступны?

Comment: А не проще переложить оригиналы за пределы папки images?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так должно сработать одной строкой, и сразу для всех альбомов

```
location ~ ^/images/[0-9]+/[^/]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: нет, не сработало

Comment: после внесения изменений, перезагрузили Nginx?

Comment: Да, перезагружаю. Вот такой метод работает  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
        deny all;
     }  Но так мы блокируем вообще все картинки, а вот с указанием папок не блокируется ничего

Comment: Я понял, можно тогда так, но лучшее прописать полный путь к папаке images, от корня

location ~ images/[0-9]+/[^/]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ {
    deny all;
}

Comment: location ~ ^/public/images/[0-9]+/[^/]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ { deny all; } Это с полным путем от корня сайта, не помогает, как только не пробовал

Comment: Надо не от корня сайта, а от корня системы, ну или:
`location ~ ^/images/ `
заменить на 
`location ~ images/ `

Comment: ) я уже и так пробывал ~ images/ и так ~ /images/ и так ~ ^/images/  и так ~ ^images/ короче все варианты перебрал, вот заблочить все получается, а вот частично никак ))

Comment: А если все-таки полный путь указать? 
Можно выполнить в консоли команду `pwd`, находясь в папке images, чтоб увидеть его

Comment: Не прокатило )) Видимо надо переписывать приложение, ибо nginx не запилен под такие блин простейшие задачи

Comment: Ну странно что не помогло, уверен что что-то пропустили

Comment: @webkostya, приложите свой конфиг. У Nginx есть приоритет обработки локейшенов. Скорее всего какой-то другой локейшн "перебивает" правило, которое написано в ответе. А блин, некропостинг

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, должно сработать:

```
location ~ /images/35/thumbs/.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$ {
   allow all;
}
location ~ /images/35/medium/.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$ {
   allow all;
}
location /images/35/.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$ {
   deny all;
}
```

nginx вроде бы смотрит правила до первого соответствия.

Comment: этот метод тоже не работает

Comment: Ну извините, я не проверял.